# Removing the deleted Member from the MDS Database - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, master-data-management, mds

I deleted one of Code from MDS which was not required initially for the process.

> Example: Code: TEST-001

Later realized this code is required and tried to re-insert this into MDS through EXCEL (MDS plugin)

MDS throws an error as below:

> Code - The member code is already used by a member that was deleted. Pick a different code or ask an administrator to remove the deleted member from the MDS database.

How to remove this member from MDS database and re-insert same.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the transaction of the deleted member to bring the member and its code back to an active state.

See here for reactivating a deleted member: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487037(v=sql.110).aspx

After that , use entity based staging to purge (permanently delete) the code from MDS.  This will require using an import type of 4 or 6.

Here is more information regarding entity based staging: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633854(v=sql.110).aspx